# Codeigniter: Head & Title Tags with if/else

Tags: php, codeigniter, if-statement, header, head

I am newbie in CodeIgniter and in PHP as well. I am looking for an example to find out how it is worked before recode it to my project. And also you can explain basically if you want without any example. I have been looking for it on the internet but I couldnt find yet. I don't know how to search about this topic on Google I guess.

I have two *header.php* files that are renamed as *header_post.php* and *header_main.php* in "views" folder.

For *header_post.php*, the meta tags such as description, title and so on are changed based on the the title and the content of the post I published.

For *header_main.php*, the meta tags such as description, title and so on are stable based on the the title and the description of my blog.

But I want to create a header.php instead of header_post.php and header_main.php. When it is in homepage of the blog the codes I wrote for header_main.php should work and on the other hand when it is in a post's page the codes I wrote for header_post.php should work.

As an example,

```
Homepage:  <title>Bari's Blog</title>
In a Post: <title>Post's Title</title>
```

I need your help about how to write if/else statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check if the variables for setting the header etc. are set:

```
<?php if (isset($title) && $title) { ?>   
<title><?php echo $title;?></title>
<?php } else { ?>
<title>Bari's Blog</title>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Yes but it's just an example.

Comment: Okey I just want to make it clear =) Thanks for your help. I will focus on your codes.